# Replace NAs in R

Tags: r

I have a huge dataframe and I want to reduce the NAs in it.
A short example how the date looks like would be something like this

| year | company | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2007 | pepsi | NA |
| 2008 | pepsi | NA |
| 2009 | pepsi | 0,5 |
| 2010 | pepsi | 2 |
| 2005 | sprite | NA |
| 2007 | sprite | NA |
| 2008 | sprite | NA |

Whenever one company has a score I want to replace the NAs with the minimum Value. But when there is no Value in any column for this company I want to keep the NA. So the date looks like this:

| year | company | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2007 | pepsi | 0,5 |
| 2008 | pepsi | 0,5 |
| 2009 | pepsi | 0,5 |
| 2010 | pepsi | 2 |
| 2005 | sprite | NA |
| 2007 | sprite | NA |
| 2008 | sprite | NA |

Here is the Code I tried:

```
df<- df %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(value= ifelse(is.na(value), min(value, na.rm = T), value))
```

However when I run this on my data I get infinite values. I think it is because I dont know how to tell r what to do when one company has no value at all.

I also tried slight variations like:

```
df<- df %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(value= ifelse(is.na(value), min(value, na.rm = T), "O"))
```

```
df<- df %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(value= ifelse(is.na(value), min(value, na.rm = T), "NA"))
```

these didn't work either.

Here is some reproducible data. I hope I provided it in the right formate (If its wrong let me know and I'll correct it!):

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c('2007','2008','2009','2010','2005','2007','2008'),
  company= c('pepsi','pepsi','pepsi','pepsi','sprite','sprite','sprite'),
  value= c(NA,NA,0.5,2,NA,NA,NA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'company', create an `if` `else` condition which checks whether `all` the elements are `NA`, then return `NA` or else apply `na.aggregate` to replace the `NA` elements with `min` (specified in `FUN`)

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>%      
   group_by(company) %>%
   mutate(value = if(all(is.na(value))) NA_real_ 
       else na.aggregate(value, FUN = "min"))
```

---

Or another option is `replace` + `if/else`

```
df %>%      
    group_by(company) %>%
    mutate(value = if(all(is.na(value))) NA_real_ else 
        replace(value, is.na(value), min(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  year  company value
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 2007  pepsi     0.5
2 2008  pepsi     0.5
3 2009  pepsi     0.5
4 2010  pepsi     2  
5 2005  sprite   NA  
6 2007  sprite   NA  
7 2008  sprite   NA
```

---

We could avoid the `if/else` with `min_` from `hablar`

```
library(hablar)
df %>%
   group_by(company) %>%
   mutate(value = replace(value, is.na(value), min_(value)))
```